# Counting the cells in a row (across multiple columns) that are within x value of first column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have the following dataframe and I'm trying to determine how many of the column values in each row are within 12 of the max value found in the first four columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    't1': [0, 0, 40, 37, 143],
    't2': [0, 38, 149, 145, 151],
    't3': [0, 140, 100, 37, 150],
't4': [0, 0, 23, 0, 19],
    'other': ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'NaN'],
    'age': [21, 29, 57, 48, 37],
'new_max': [0,140,149,145,151]})
```

I want to check columns 't1' through 't4' to see if they are within 12 of the maximum value contained in those four columns for that row.

The output would be to add a 'w12_count' column for each row like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    't1': [0, 0, 40, 37, 143],
    't2': [0, 38, 149, 145, 151],
    't3': [0, 140, 100, 37, 150],
't4': [0, 0, 23, 0, 19],
    'other': ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'NaN'],
    'age': [21, 29, 57, 48, 37],
'new_max': [0,140,149,145,151],
'w12_count': [4, 1, 1, 1, 3]})
```

I know I could use .loc to create a new column based on each column I'm checking and assign it 0 if it is false or 1 if it is true and then sum those new columns to get the count.  But my data actually has a lot of columns so I'm trying to find the syntax for using the count method to total the number of columns within 12 and assign a new column with the count.

Comment: What do you mean by *if they are within 12 of the maximum value* ? could you explain the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `filter` the `t` like columns, then take the `max` along `axis=1` on these columns then subtract the `max` value from these columns to get the difference then compare the absolute value of difference with `12` to create a boolean mask followed by `sum` along `axis=1` to get the counts

```
t = df.filter(regex=r't\d+')
df['w12_count'] = t.sub(t.max(1), axis=0).abs().le(12).sum(1)
```

---

```
    t1   t2   t3  t4 other  age  new_max  w12_count
0    0    0    0   0  str1   21        0          4
1    0   38  140   0  str2   29      140          1
2   40  149  100  23  str3   57      149          1
3   37  145   37   0  str4   48      145          1
4  143  151  150  19   NaN   37      151          3
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was trying to do.  I don't quite get what you did with the first line - but it works! - so I'm looking through the python documentation to try to figure out how regex works.  https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html EDIT: It looks like the filter will get anything that starts with 't and \d+ is a matching expression - that is incredibly helpful.

Comment: @mgadfly Pleased to help. `filter` can be used with a `regex` pattern to select the subset of columns where the column name matches the regex pattern, so `t\d+` matches all columns names starting with `t` and followed by one or more digits.